# PHP failing to start (stalling) on Debian 12 fresh upgrade

Tags: php, debian

I just upgraded to Debian 12 on my home server and noticed that my PHP webpages were broken.

I already started the obvious :

- reboot
- apt update && upgrade
- apt install php --reinstall
- systemctl restart apache2

nothing fixed anything, that seems to be the thing that broke on the upgrade.

I tried to start PHP by running `php` and `php8.2` but they are stalling and never show a PHP console...

I had no problem/warning what so ever in upgrading my system from 11 to 12 and tried to reinstall php with no success on getting it to work.

Here is the `ltrace php` output, it seems to always stall at the same step. I really have no idea on how to tackle this issue.

```
...
NCONF_free(0x7f5ebe668338, 0x7ffd9fa18a60, 15, 3)                                                                    = 0
memcpy(0x7f5ebe669258, "", 0)                                                                                        = 0x7f5ebe669258
chroot(0x555b875cb76c, 0x7ffd9fa18b80, 0x555b876e2440, 0x555b876e2440)                                               = 15
memcpy(0x7ffd9fa18a60, "PATH_TRANSLATED\0", 16)                                                                      = 0x7ffd9fa18a60
strncmp("PATH_TRANSLATED", "__Host-", 7)                                                                             = -15
strncmp("PATH_TRANSLATED", "__Secure-", 9)                                                                           = -15
memcpy(0x7f5ebe668360, "PATH_TRANSLATED", 15)                                                                        = 0x7f5ebe668360
chroot(0x555b875cb76c, 0x7ffd9fa18b70, 0x555b876f7570, 0x555b876f7570)                                               = 15
memcpy(0x7ffd9fa18a60, "PATH_TRANSLATED\0", 16)                                                                      = 0x7ffd9fa18a60
strncmp("PATH_TRANSLATED", "__Host-", 7)                                                                             = -15
strncmp("PATH_TRANSLATED", "__Secure-", 9)                                                                           = -15
NCONF_free(0x7f5ebe668360, 0x7ffd9fa18a60, 15, 3)                                                                    = 0
memcpy(0x7f5ebe669278, "", 0)                                                                                        = 0x7f5ebe669278
chroot(0x555b875cb77c, 0x7ffd9fa18b80, 0x555b876e2440, 0x555b876e2440)                                               = 13
memcpy(0x7ffd9fa18a60, "DOCUMENT_ROOT\0", 14)                                                                        = 0x7ffd9fa18a60
strncmp("DOCUMENT_ROOT", "__Host-", 7)                                                                               = -27
strncmp("DOCUMENT_ROOT", "__Secure-", 9)                                                                             = -27
memcpy(0x7f5ebe668388, "DOCUMENT_ROOT", 13)                                                                          = 0x7f5ebe668388
chroot(0x555b875cb77c, 0x7ffd9fa18b70, 0x555b876f7570, 0x555b876f7570)                                               = 13
memcpy(0x7ffd9fa18a60, "DOCUMENT_ROOT\0", 14)                                                                        = 0x7ffd9fa18a60
strncmp("DOCUMENT_ROOT", "__Host-", 7)                                                                               = -27
strncmp("DOCUMENT_ROOT", "__Secure-", 9)                                                                             = -27
NCONF_free(0x7f5ebe668388, 0x7ffd9fa18a60, 13, 0x2bad79f90a0a9660)                                                   = 0
fflush(0x7ffd9fa18c00)                                                                                               = 0
memcpy(0x7f5ebe6021c8, "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT", 18)                                                                     = 0x7f5ebe6021c8
memcpy(0x7f5ebe6683b0, "REQUEST_TIME", 12)                                                                           = 0x7f5ebe6683b0
_setjmp(0x7ffd9fa17af0, 0xffffffff, 0x555b875cc540, 0x7ffd9fa18ee0)                                                  = 0
gzeof(0x7f5ec0d8fa80, 0x7ffd9fa16678, 0x7ffd9fa16680, 0x7ffd9fa17af0)                                                = 0
EVP_rc2_64_cbc(0, 0x7ffd9fa16678, 0x7ffd9fa16680, 0x7ffd9fa17af0)                                                    = 1
PEM_read_bio_CMS(0x7ffd9fa165f7, 1, 1, 0x7f5ec0d8fa80 <no return ...>
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) ---
puts("\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !"...) = -1097360632
puts("\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !"...) = -1097360632
EVP_PKEY_get_utf8_string_param(2, 0, 0x7ffd9fa15d30, 0)                                                              = 0
pcre2_match_8(0x7ffd9fa15d38, 0, 0, 0x7f5ec0bf905f)                                                                  = 0
pcre2_match_8(0x7ffd9fa15cb0, 0, 0, 0x7f5ec0bf905f)                                                                  = 0
EVP_ripemd160(0x7ffd9fa15cb0, 2, 0, 0x7f5ec0bf905f)                                                                  = 0
EVP_PKEY_get_utf8_string_param(2, 0x7ffd9fa15d30, 0, 1)                                                              = 0
crypto_pwhash_str_needs_rehash(1, 0x7ffd9fa15cb0, 0, 0x7f5ec0bf905f)                                                 = 0
rename("\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 "..., "\002") = 1905913
fstat(0x1d14f9, 2, 0, 0x7f5ec0c922e7 <no return ...>
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

`strace -yyttT php` output:

```
...
02:25:22.911980 read(3</usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab>, "", 4096) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.912023 close(3</usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab>) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.912184 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</home/USER>, "/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=114, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000012>
02:25:22.912342 brk(0x55d5de7fb000)     = 0x55d5de7fb000 <0.000013>
02:25:22.912480 futex(0x7fbce15eeb28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.912634 futex(0x7fbce127ddcc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.912702 futex(0x7fbce127ddc0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000025>
02:25:22.912801 futex(0x7fbce127ddb8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.912853 futex(0x7fbce127dec0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.913101 futex(0x7fbce127dda8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.913202 futex(0x7fbce127dda0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000024>
02:25:22.913317 futex(0x7fbce127d824, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000027>
02:25:22.913385 futex(0x7fbce127de04, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.913422 futex(0x7fbce127d818, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000023>
02:25:22.914016 futex(0x7fbce127ddb0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000029>
02:25:22.914089 openat(AT_FDCWD</home/USER>, "/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf> <0.000015>
02:25:22.914164 futex(0x7fbce127d8e8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.914203 newfstatat(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12332, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0 <0.000028>
02:25:22.914318 read(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuratio"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000011>
02:25:22.914433 read(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "he listed attributes must be the"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000010>
02:25:22.914628 read(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "R hex encoding of an extension: "..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000010>
02:25:22.914793 read(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "\noldcert = $insta::certout # ins"..., 4096) = 44 <0.000026>
02:25:22.914917 read(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>, "", 4096) = 0 <0.000026>
02:25:22.915014 close(3</etc/ssl/openssl.cnf>) = 0 <0.000023>
02:25:22.915182 futex(0x7fbce127dd98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.915238 futex(0x7fbce1442844, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000022>
02:25:22.915359 futex(0x7fbce1442864, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.915503 mmap(NULL, 196608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbcde161000 <0.000016>
02:25:22.915606 brk(0x55d5de81e000)     = 0x55d5de81e000 <0.000030>
02:25:22.916029 brk(0x55d5de83f000)     = 0x55d5de83f000 <0.000014>
02:25:22.916293 brk(0x55d5de860000)     = 0x55d5de860000 <0.000013>
02:25:22.916595 brk(0x55d5de881000)     = 0x55d5de881000 <0.000044>
02:25:22.916935 brk(0x55d5de8a5000)     = 0x55d5de8a5000 <0.000031>
02:25:22.917224 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0 <0.000028>
02:25:22.917351 getrandom("\x8b\xe6\xb4\x62\xcc\x93\x1d\xa3\x15\xce\x43\x77\x31\x8a\x3f\x53", 16, 0) = 16 <0.000010>
02:25:22.917455 getrandom("\x82\x04\x18\x22\xb3\x55\x1c\xb2\xeb\x68\x82\xbb\x78\x05\x3e\xf9", 16, 0) = 16 <0.000022>
02:25:22.917743 mmap(NULL, 331776, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbcde110000 <0.000014>
02:25:22.917906 munmap(0x7fbcde191000, 167936) = 0 <0.000066>
02:25:22.918140 brk(0x55d5de8c6000)     = 0x55d5de8c6000 <0.000026>
02:25:22.918437 brk(0x55d5de8f4000)     = 0x55d5de8f4000 <0.000013>
02:25:22.918744 getpid()                = 14978 <0.000009>
02:25:22.918791 rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000013>
02:25:22.918878 rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000012>
02:25:22.918937 rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.919001 rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.919072 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000025>
02:25:22.919173 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.919247 rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.919285 rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000022>
02:25:22.919365 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000022>
02:25:22.919430 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.919470 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.919509 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000023>
02:25:22.919576 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.919629 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000009>
02:25:22.919669 rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, {sa_handler=0x55d5ddca29d0, sa_mask=~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbce0c50f90}, NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000010>
02:25:22.919710 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PROF], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000023>
02:25:22.919786 ioctl(0</dev/pts/0<char 136:0>>, TCGETS, {c_iflag=ICRNL|IXON|IUTF8, c_oflag=NL0|CR0|TAB0|BS0|VT0|FF0|OPOST|ONLCR, c_cflag=B38400|CS8|CREAD, c_lflag=ISIG|ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|IEXTEN|ECHOCTL|ECHOKE, ...}) = 0 <0.000012>
02:25:22.919893 newfstatat(0</dev/pts/0<char 136:0>>, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0 <0.000011>
02:25:22.919948 read(0</dev/pts/0<char 136:0>>, ^Cstrace: Process 14978 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Comment: home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com

Comment: Could you add the output of `strace -yyttT ...` ?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't the right place... I thought this was more appropriate, I initially planned to ask this in StackOverflow but debian's topic was redirecting questions about Debian based server administration here.

Comment: Just in case, I added strace's output, but do tell me if it is better to close my post and try somewhere else!